# Need to click twice to render data

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a data table that have to be loaded after clicking a command button, but to render the table I have to click twice the button. How I can fix this?

Portion of the code:

```
<h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText id="search" value="#{searchBean.user}" required="true"/>
            <p:commandButton id="searching" action="#{searchBean.search()}" value="search">
                <f:ajax execute="searching" render="datascroller" />
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:dataScroller  id="datascroller" value="#{searchBean.users}" var="user" chunkSize="10">
......
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
<h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText id="search" value="#{searchBean.user}" required="true"/>
            <p:commandButton id="searching" actionListener="#{searchBean.search}" value="search" process="searching" update="datascroller"/>
            <p:dataScroller  id="datascroller" value="#{searchBean.users}" var="user" chunkSize="10">
```